# Get data from main thread when something happens in another?

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently I have a Thread running a Socket listening for connections. When it receives a connection, it needs to upload data gathered in the main thread (i.e. grab data from main thread). However I pass an instance of the Object, but it's never updated with the data that's collected while waiting for a connection.

Is there a proper way to do this? I've googled around and can't seem to find a concrete answer.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

---

Hopefully this makes sense, but i'll try to explain more with an examples.

```
class MainThread {
    private void MainThread() {
        SomeObj obj = new SomeObj("DATA Needed");

        SecondThread second = new SecondThread(obj);
        second.start();
    }
}

class SecondThread extends Thread {
    SomeObj obj;

    public void SecondThread(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {

    //Listening for connection
    //Connection get!
    //Get updated data (Object obj) from main thread.
    //Upload
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give me. Please let me know if I am approaching this completely wrong! I would rather learn AND get answers than just get answers.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it receives a connection, it needs to upload data gathered in the main thread (i.e. grab data from main thread).

This doesn't make sense as you don't get information from *Threads*, you get information and communicate with *Objects*. That's a big difference. You need to pass an instance of the object that you need information from into the second object that needs this information, perhaps as a parameter in its constructor. Then you would set a field in  your SecondThread class with this instance and you can call methods on it.

i.e.,

```
class MainThread {
    private void MainThread() {
        SomeType obj = new SomeType("DATA Needed");

        SecondThread second = new SecondThread(obj);
        second.start();
    }
}

class SecondThread extends Thread {
    SomeType obj;

    public SecondThread(SomeType obj) {
       this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {
      // can call methods on obj here
    }
}
```

Hopefully you're not actually using an Object type but rather a much more specific type of object, right?

Comment: Right, I have actually been doing that, Sorry I forgot to mention. But they always turn up with the data that has been added while it waits. Editing question.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been trying, but the instance that I get is never updated with the data collected while waiting for a connection. Thanks for your time! (As for your question at the bottom of your answer: yes.)

Comment: Expanding on this answer... you might want to pass an iterator over a queue of stuff-to-be-uploaded into the uploaders constructor... ergo: a classic producer-consumer pattern... the trick will be avoiding "busy waiting" in the consumer when the queue is empty.

Comment: @corlettk: hey Keith! Long time no see!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far, and sorry for my poor explanations. This is what I've been trying, but let me try again, as I could have done something improperly.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Yes Pete I was a very busy boy for a year or more, but I'm a man of leisure at the moment... forced redundancy, so I've spending far-too-much time online lately. I should be looking for work, but the local IT market is completely fubared (that's the polite version) thanks mainly to the moron that just took over our state government writing-off 30% of it's IT workforce (in a city where about 60% of IT was state government) so there's not really much point... I'll have to go work on the mines for a while. Sigh.

Comment: @corlettk: or move to where you'd be better appreciated!

Comment: I was thinking of going state-side... atleast houses are cheap there ;-)

Comment: Gaah, I feel so ridiculous right now. This is what i've been doing, and it has been working, it's the passing of the instance of the data collector I messed up. Sorry, and thanks agian.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limited set of events that ensure a write in one thread is visible in another. Thread creation is one of them, so any data written into obj initially should be available in the second thread.

One option would be to synchronize on obj. If the main thread only modified it by calling its synchronized methods and the second thread got the data from an obj synchronized method the main thread writes would be visible in the second thread.

If you really want to learn about multi-threading in Java, I recommend [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my rather cryptic comment on Hovercraft Full Of Eels answer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*; // BlockingQueue

class MainThread {
    private void MainThread() {
        // BlockingQueue is designed to be used primarily for producer-
        // consumer queues, so ALL implementations are thread-safe!
        new UploaderThread(new LinkedBlockingQueue<Data>()).start();
    }
}

class UploaderThread extends Thread {
    private final BlockingQueue<Data> _dataToBeUploaded;
    public SecondThread(BlockingQueue<Data> dataToBeUploaded) {
       _dataToBeUploaded = dataToBeUploaded;
    }
    public void run() {
      while ( true ) {
        // Retrieve the first element in the queue, if necessary waiting 
        // until an element becomes available.
        upload(_dataToBeUploaded.take()); 
      }
    }
}
```

Cheers. Keith.