# Run two tasks at the same time changing one variable

Tags: java, feed, multitasking

My question is related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191029/running-two-independent-tasks-simultaneously-using-threads). I basically want to do two tasks at the same time :

1. collect data from a feed and add it to the list of objects
2. read the
   list of objects, add it to the db and remove what is added to the db
   from the list of objects

So I am changing a list of objects in these two separate task and I am not sure how to share it and making it available to change by the two tasks running at the same time.
The reason why I want to do it in two different task is because data from a feed is given usually every 5 seconds which gives me not enough time to process it and add it to the db.

I hope someone can help. thank you.

---- edit

I found another question which seems to give me what I need from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225684/get-data-from-main-thread-when-something-happens-in-another). So at the moment I have a code like so:

```
class MainThread {
    private void MainThread() {
        while(true)
       {
         //get json data

        List<Object> obj = //json data to list of object;        

        SecondThread second = new SecondThread(obj);
        second.start();
       }

    }
}

class SecondThread extends Thread {
    List<Object> obj;

    public void SecondThread(List<Object> obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {

    //add list to db

    }
}
```

What I am wondering is if the while loop in the MainThread waits for the SecondThread to finish processing/putting the data in the db before it starts another loop?

Comment: Do you mean tasks, or threads? ("Task" is often taken to mean "process".) Note that if you can't manipulate the data within 5 seconds, a second thread may not improve your throughput unless it runs on another processor... and even then may not help depending on what the limiting factor is. You may instead need a data-gathering thread that can keep up with the incoming data, which queues work to one or more processing threads that take as long as necessary.

Comment: Sorry I suppose I meant threads. Your suggestion with the data-gathering thread sounds like what I need. Do you mind giving me an example please?

Comment: There are many examples and tutorials on the web of Java programming with threads. Take a look at them, try something based on one of them, come back to us with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like you found something for your first set of questions, I'll answer your last question:

> What I am wondering is if the while loop in the MainThread waits for the SecondThread to finish processing/putting the data in the db before it starts another loop?

In your example `MainThread` is never going to wait for `SecondThread` to finish, it will continually execute its while loop.  In your code you are creating `SecondThread` inside of a while loop which will create tons of threads before your app crashes.  If you want to wait for a thread to complete before doing other stuff then you can do:

```
SecondThread second = new SecondThread(obj);
second.start();
second.join(); //will make current thread wait until this thread finishes before proceeding
```

Note that a thread join in your case will essentially just make your code sequential since SecondThread will block MainThread from running.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you think theres a more elegant solution for question 1? I really just want the thread collecting data with the while loop to run by itself whilst the other thread adds stuff to the database...

Comment: @obsessiveCookie I would search for the producer/consumer design strategy.  Basically consumer threads will wait if there is no data to process.  Producer threads will add data to a shared collection, and then notify a consumer thread that there is work to be done.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I now know where to look!